# Cubesat Orbit calculation

Tags: low-earth-orbit, cubesat, calculation, orbital-lifetime

I am trying to calculate the orbit parameters for a cubesat (Duration, eclipse time and sun time) can someone help please

Comment: We need a bit more data before we can calculate anything. What altitude and inclination are you planning to use, for instance?

Comment: What information do you have?  Are you planning an orbit for a project, or are you getting some information about an existing cubesat?  Without a better question, we can't give a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get this information is to use a tool such as the Satellite Tool Kit (STK). Essentially, this information varies over time, especially for high inclination orbits. A good orbital simulator will allow you to enter mean altitude, inclination, and eccentricity (Or alternatively apogee/ perigee/inclination)

If you already have the satellite in orbit, then you can import the satellite into STK, by looking up the satellite from their orbit. The eclipse times are an available report.